# Ubuntu 16.04 and apt-fast

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, auto-completion, apt-fast

I have installed `apt-fast` in three sites, my own laptop, inside a virtual machine (`Ubuntu Server 14.04`) and in a remote public server (`Ubuntu Server 14.04` too). Autocompletion of `apt-fast` works well in both servers, but it doesn't in my Ubuntu 16.04 personal OS.

What can I do to recover autocompletion, or at least, to know what is happening?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem but none of the solutions provided work.

So, I proceeded to create the apt-fast file:

```
cd /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/
sudo touch apt-fast
sudo cp apt-fast /etc/bash_completion.d/
sudo chown root:root /etc/bash_completion.d/apt-fast
. /etc/bash_completion
```

Cheers!
Oh! you must logout and login to see the effects!

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue. In my case it was the absence of `/etc/bash_completion.d/apt-fast`.

I referred to the [Github page of the project](https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast) and the Autocompletion section in README was helpful.

```
sudo cp completions/bash/apt-fast /etc/bash_completion.d/
sudo chown root:root /etc/bash_completion.d/apt-fast
. /etc/bash_completion
```